# Plot between multiple curves

Tags: plotting, filling

I have three functions, `U1`, `U2`, `Dead`.  I would like to fill the area between the three curves when `U2` is (only) above both `U1` and `Dead`. This raises two issues relative to what I can find online.  One is dealing with three vs. two curves filling and one is that the filling ends up only on a region.  (I can find some things online on the latter---but I need a solution that works with the three curves.)

To be more specific: the functions are

```
U1[del_] = (1 - del)/del
U2[del_] = del
Dead[del_] = del*del*del
```

and right now I have

```
Plot[{U1[del], U2[del], Dead[del]},
   {del, 0, 1},
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, Thick}, {Red, Dashed, Thick}, {Green, Dashed, Thick}},
   Filling -> {2 -> {3}},
   Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This filled between `U2` and `Dead`.  But I want the filling to be between `U2` and `Max[U1, Dead]` and only when `U2` is above the max.

Any help would be appreciated.  Apologies if I am writing in the wrong format---I am new. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly applaud Dr. belisarius' use of an invisible curve to control the filling, but I think the following implementation of his idea is easier to understand.

```
U1[del_] := (1 - del)/del
U2[del_] := del
Dead[del_] := del^3

controlCurve[del_] :=
  Piecewise[
    {{U2[del], U1[del] > U2[del]},
     {U1[del], U1[del] > Dead[del]}},
    Dead[del]]

Plot[{U1[del], U2[del], Dead[del], controlCurve[del]}, {del, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  PlotStyle ->
    {{Blue, Dashed, Thick}, {Red, Dashed, Thick}, 
     {Green, Dashed, Thick}, Transparent},
  Filling -> {2 -> {{4}, Yellow}},
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thanks m_goldberg---indeed this is easier to understand!

Comment: C'est véritablement utile puisque c'est joli.

Answer (score 10):

```
f[s_] := Plot[{U1[del], U2[del], Dead[del], 
              If[s[U2[del], #], #, U2[del]] &@Max[U1[del], Dead[del]]}, 
              {del, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
              PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed, Thick},
                           {Red, Dashed, Thick}, 
                           {Green, Dashed, Thick}, 
                            Transparent}, 
              Filling -> {2 -> {4}}, Frame -> True]

f /@ {Less, Greater}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks!  this is awesome!  i appreciate it!

Comment: May I bother you with a follow up: Would it be possible to explain the role of the "#" in this bit: If[s[U2[del], #], #, U2[del]] &@Max[U1[del], Dead[del]]}?  Just want to understand/learn. Thanks again!